# How can I apply dynamic forecolor to text-field in JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a textfield in the jasperreport. Now I need to pass the text-color of that field dynamically.

I have tried using iReport designer but couldn't find any relevant solutions so far.

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Style` with conditions. Or you can use different elements (textField, for example) with visibility condition - `printWhenExpression`.

For more details you can see this [discussion](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=50742).

The sample of using `Style`. Sets `forecolor` property of "Product position" `textField` to *red* when product's cost is greater than *12.0* and less or equal than *14.0* and sets it to *green* if cost greater than *14.0*:

```
<style name="ColoredField">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf($F{PRODUCT_COST} > 12.0 && $F{PRODUCT_COST} <= 14.0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#FF0000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf($F{PRODUCT_COST} > 14.0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#00FF99"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
 ...
<detail>
    <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement style="ColoredField" x="78" y="1" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: @Alex... nice descriptive answer... But in my case i have different 6 possibilities of color that can be applied to the text field. Any chances to implement it?

Comment: Yes, you can. You should create six `conditionalStyles`